# Adverbs before adjectives

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Generally speaking, adverbs modify verbs, and adjectives modify nouns. However, I guess adverbs can modify nouns as well. With that said, I recently came across the following sentence that just struck me as off:

It would be an extremely uphill battle.

I feel like you can have an extreme uphill battle, but not an extremely uphill battle. Something feels off about this sentence, but I could just be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's is an alarmingly common misconception that adverbs modify verbs. Or rather, a common incomplete understanding. Adverbs modify verbs, and also adjectives. They can also modify other adverbs, and sometimes a whole phrase - even a noun phrase. Mostly it's verbs, adjectives and other adverbs, though.

We can see that ***extremely*** here is an adverb, and modifies ***uphill***. It is an adverb of degree, like *very* or *slightly*, which you are likely to have seen modify adjectives before:

> This bit of grammar is **slightly** difficult.
>   This is a **very** tasty meal.

Thus, this battle is uphill to a great degree. *Extremely* usually denotes a greater degree than *very*, so we're looking at it being really, really uphill. This is metaphorical, of course, but it's strengthening the degree of the metaphor itself.

Your alternative, an "**extreme** uphill battle", would be two adjectives both modifying *battle*. It would be both an uphill battle, and an extreme battle, whatever that might mean.

I can see why teachers might tell people that adjectives modify nouns and adverbs modify verbs. It helps keep things simple, easy to learn and follow. But they really ought to correct that pretty soon afterwards to say that adverbs can modify adjectives as well. I mean, you've probably been using *very* since fairly early in language lessons, so I guess the teacher just never mentioned that *very* is an adverb...

Answer (score 2):

Adverbs can modify verbs *or* adjectives. In this case "extremely" modifies "uphill". And "uphill" is an adjective modifying "battle".

Comment: Thanks. So is that a proper sentence? I don't know why it sounds off to me.

Comment: @user27343: It's awkward phrasing, but there's nothing *wrong* with it.